# Javascript margin left on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the margin left to stop at a certain point

```js
var data = $('#nexttologodiv').css('margin-left');
var init = 220, 
    $page = $('#nexttologodiv').css('margin-left', init);

console.log(data);

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (data == '220px'){
    $page.removeClass( 'scrolled' );
    console.log(window.scrollY);
    $page.css('margin-left', init - window.scrollY * 2);
  }
  else if (window.scrollY <= 48) {
    $page.css('margin-left', 0 - window.scrollY);
  }}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to achieve. Can you share with us the full code, or **even better** create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com) that reproduce the problem?